# How to make a full width sub-menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to make a full width drop down sub-menu. Please check my site. My site is [here](http://www.samgyoyu.com).

I tried these code but it's not working. I put these code to child theme's style css.

```
#masthead .color-site-white nav .sub-menu {
left: 0;
right: 0; }

#masthead .color-site-white nav .sub-menu {
width:100% }
```

I don't know how to do it.. Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle with your example

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by a "full width drop down sub-menu". Do you mean the options that appear under "Dream Race"?

Comment: @tilix Thank you for your comment:) But I'm beginner of this, I don't know how to do it. I'm sorry.

Comment: @ferrarifan Thank you for your comment:) Yes That's what I mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link isn`t showing. 
By setting the width of the dropdown to 100% you should achieve it, something like this:

```
#masthead ul li:hover > ul {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

have you seen this? [Full width css dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261421/full-width-css-dropdown-menu)

Comment: Hi, Andrei:) Thank you for your answer but it's not working.. And I fix my link. Sorry:(

Comment: i`v seen, replace from #masthead .top-strip nav > ul > li the part "position: relative;" to "position:static" and then replace from #masthead .top-strip nav .sub-menu the part "width: 160px;" to "width: 100%;"