# html - Make a <div> as wide as the page, while inside another <div>

Tags: html, css, width

I have a container `<div>`, in which I have another, called `.dropdown`. I want to have `.dropdown` to have the same `width` as the whole page. `width: 100%` seemed reasonable, but than I got that `.dropdown` was as wide as `.container`.

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href=''>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=''>Products</a>
            <div class='dropdown'>
                <p>Some content</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=''>About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=''>Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=''>Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
div.dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Any way of fixing this?

Sincerly,

Jasper

Someone gently flagged this question as duplicated, but it isn't, because in the concerned question ([Full width css dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261421/full-width-css-dropdown-menu][1])) focuses on the text *inside* `.dropdown`, this question focusses the whole `<div>`.

Comment: You'll be needing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261421/full-width-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: @Stefan And it's a dupe by the way.

Comment: Yea sorry, flagged it as a dupe after it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, I guess I haven't done enought research.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try to make

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You surely don't need `height:100%`?... Also, are you sure this will work?

Comment: i think it will since he didn't put position in it's parent div's style

Comment: This acctually works, I only needed to change some margins, as `.dropdown` shot strait up my page, so thanks :)

Comment: Why people downvoted the choose answer?..

Comment: @HenriqueM. i really don't know :(

Answer (score -2):

Theoretically, you can't do that. Since the child `width` is conducted/relative by the parent's behavior, you will either need to specify a parent with full page width or set `position: absolute;` to the child.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out myself, that's why I ask