# Full width Submenu with Level 2 and Level 3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to extend the same concept to level3 submenu with full background color . [Full width css dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261421/full-width-css-dropdown-menu) . My Css is something like this for level 2 & 3:

```
.level_3 {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 -1000em;
}

.level_2 {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  padding: 0 1000em;
  margin: 0 -1000em;
  z-index: 101;
  background: rgba(255, 240, 240, 0.8);
  li {
    a {
      @include line-height(30px);
      text-transform: none;
    }
  }
}
```

I need to make the level2 height same as that of level3 without min-height as it can any number of level3 submenu.Here is my pen to briefly demonstrate: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VGvqxm

[image: I need the background color to go till the end of submenu level3 as well]

Comment: Share your HTML.

Comment: Its there is the codepen link, HTML and CSS